# Python: Attempting to make a matrix out of DataFrame from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm importing some data from a database into a DataFrame object using Pandas. The data's format is as follows:

```
time   info    from    to    frequency
19:00  ...      A      X        20
19:00  ...      B      Z         9
21:00  ...      A      Y         2
21:00  ...      A      Z         5
23:55  ...      A      X         8
```

Now, I have two problems I need to solve:

1. Count the sum of the frequencies of every movement from point to point independently of time, such that from point A to point X this sum would be 28. So as you may guess, "time" and "key" are disposable keys, I do not need them in this situation.
2. Since I can guarantee that all points in "from" are the same as in "to", I would like to have such sums mentioned above in form of a matrix of some sort.

I was already solving both of these with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def make_matrix(df: pd.DataFrame):

    # Get grouped version, discarding date and info...
    grouped = df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['frequency'].sum()

    # Fill dictionary acting as matrix...
    D = {}
    for (_from, _to), freq in grouped.items():
        if D.get(_from):
            D[_from][_to] = int(freq)
        else:
            D[_from] = {}
```

For context, the first line turns the example DataFrame into:

```
from    to    frequency
   A     X        28
         Y         2
         Z         5
   B     Z         9
```

Thing is, I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing this, but I can't find it elsewhere in StackOverflow or Google, since this is a pretty particular situation.

Also I'm looking for a better way because this dictionary ends up without the None/0 value for every instance of point X to the same point X.

I was thinking there should be an easier way to merge these columns without them ending up in the format of `grouped: pd.Series`, since having to iterate over each tuple like `(A,X),(A,Y),(A,Z)` and such as well as having to artificially add None to the trivial case of (X,X) in the dictionary felt very hacky...

Edit 1: I'm adding the desired matrix output...
It should be something like this:

```
    A     B    ...    X    Y    Z
A  null   0    ...   28    2    5
B   0    null  ...    0    0    9
.
.
.
X   0     0    ...    0    0    0
Y   0     0    ...    0    0    0
Z   0     0    ...    0    0    0
```

additionally, if there was another tuple such as from `X` to `A` with frequency 25 in the matrix position M[X][A] there would be 0 instead of 25.

Edit 2:
It is possible I'm indexing wrong, it could be the transposed matrix instead of the example one, either way you get the problem, it is a non-simetric squared matrix.

Comment: Could you post the desired matrix output? `make_matrix` doesn't actually work on my end.

Comment: Unless you provided the expected output, it will be very difficult for someone to figure out whats in your head. I think you want a matrix of `from` with all values `A, B, X, Y, Z` and `to` with all values of `A, B, X, Y, Z`. For the matrix, rows A thru Z, column A thru Z, you want to find the intersection to show the frequency.  Something like [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/gfvDV5Jb57_wcyqbdLHlw8gXObo=/655x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/times-table-598819b96f53ba0011f4d0f7.gif) where the yellow part is None and all others with frequency if it exists

Comment: I am sorry, I thought it was clear, I realize it is not. Just updated with the expected output. It is exactly as in the link you provided @JoeFerndz, thank you :)

Comment: @tdy it should work now, I added a ```def``` that was missing, my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['frequency'].sum()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Try writing this one and I am sure you will get the right output

Comment: How is this different from @Quang Hoang's answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
(df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['frequency'].sum()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
to     X  Y  Z
from          
A     28  2  5
B      0  0  9
```

Now, if you want all the destination available, you can use `reindex`:

```
all_cols = sorted(set(df['from']).union(set(df['to'])) )

(df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['frequency'].sum()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reindex(all_cols, fill_value=0)
   .reindex(all_cols, fill_value=0, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
to    A  B   X  Y  Z
from                
A     0  0  28  2  5
B     0  0   0  0  9
X     0  0   0  0  0
Y     0  0   0  0  0
Z     0  0   0  0  0
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't match the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the columns and just keep `from`, `to`, and `frequency`. Then do a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) on it to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'time'     :['19:00']*4 + ['20:00']*3 + ['21:00']*4,
                    'from'     :['A','B','A','A','B','X','Y','Z','X','A','Z'],
                    'to'       :['X','Z','Y','Z','X','B','A','B','Z','X','Y'],
                    'frequency':[20 ,  9,  2,  5,  8, 10, 20,  6,  8,  3,  7],
                    'othercols':['junk']*11})

print (df)

df = df[['from','to','frequency']]

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['frequency'],index=['from'],columns=['to'],aggfunc=sum, margins=False)

print (df1)
```

The output of this will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
     time from to  frequency othercols
0   19:00    A  X         20      junk
1   19:00    B  Z          9      junk
2   19:00    A  Y          2      junk
3   19:00    A  Z          5      junk
4   20:00    B  X          8      junk
5   20:00    X  B         10      junk
6   20:00    Y  A         20      junk
7   21:00    Z  B          6      junk
8   21:00    X  Z          8      junk
9   21:00    Y  X          3      junk
10  21:00    Z  Y          7      junk
```

Result as Expected DataFrame:

```
     frequency                      
to           A     B     X    Y    Z
from                                
A          NaN   NaN  23.0  2.0  5.0
B          NaN   NaN   8.0  NaN  9.0
X          NaN  10.0   NaN  NaN  8.0
Y         20.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
Z          NaN   6.0   NaN  7.0  NaN
```

If there is a mapping between row and column, and the value exists, it will sum and put it in the grid. We have two values from `A` to `X`. It sums it up (20 + 3) and puts it in the grid.

If you want the `NaN` values to be `0`, then you can give:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['frequency'],index=['from'],columns=['to'],aggfunc=sum, margins=False).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output will be:

```
     frequency              
to           A   B   X  Y  Z
from                        
A            0   0  23  2  5
B            0   0   8  0  9
X            0  10   0  0  8
Y           20   0   0  0  0
Z            0   6   0  7  0
```